# How could I stop a form submit in this case?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

My intention is to check some conditions before submit is done or stop it and show an alert if the results of that condition are false. I need to ask a function localized in another PHP document using POST. 
The next case I'm going to show, the alert is showed correctly when "result != 1", but when I test the opposite case "result == 1", the submit doesnt work:

```
$('body').on("submit","#idForm",function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post( 'php_file_rute.php', {action:'functionName'})
            .done(function(result) {
                if (result == 1) {
                    if(functionNameInSameJSPage()){
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('error');
                    return false;
                }              
            });
    });
```

I tried in another way, putting event.preventDefault behind every "Return false" but when "result != 1" it shows the alert but do the submit anyways. It happens in every condition (submit doesnt stop).

```
$('body').on("submit","#formProyecto",function(event) {

    $.post( 'php_file_rute.php', {action:'functionName'})
        .done(function(result) {
            if (result == 1) {
                if(functionNameInSameJSPage()){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            } else {
                alert("error");
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }              
        });
});
```

As you can see, my goal is to stop the submit if "result != 1" and show an alert or do the submit if all conditions are ok.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show `console.log(result)` value?

Comment: Consider using https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: console.lo(result) value is 1 or 0, I have checked several times.

Comment: @F.Reyes have you tried by answer? it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that you cannot return anything from an asynchronous function - which your AJAX request is.

To solve this you need to use `preventDefault()` to stop the form submit event through jQuery, then raise another *native* submit event if the AJAX request returns a valid result. This second submit event will not be handled by jQuery and will submit the form as you require. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("submit", "#idForm", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this;

  $.post('php_file_rute.php', {
    action: 'functionName'
  }).done(function(result) {
    if (result === 1) {
      if (functionNameInSameJSPage()) {
        form.submit();
      }
    } else {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
});
```

This is assuming that `functionNameInSameJSPage()` is not an async function. If it is then you'll need to use the callback pattern there too.

Comment: Hi Rory. It just tried it and it stops well the submit and shows the alert, but the submit doesnt work when results === 1. Still stopped even with this.submit() (it causes an error) or $(this).submit(), or $('idForm).submit().

Comment: Are you sure `result` is an integer? Try `result == "1"`

Comment: Yes, its an integer but there isnt the problem. When I call the submit again after all the validations, it creates a infinite loop (a submit event calls the same submit).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a tricky one but you can kind of get it to work by doing:

```
$('body').on("submit","#idForm",function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post( 'php_file_rute.php', {action:'functionName'})
            .done(function(result) {
                if (result == 1) {
                    if(functionNameInSameJSPage()){
                        $('#idForm').trigger("submit.force"); //Trigger submit again but under a different name
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('error');
                }              
            });
    });
    $('body').on("submit.force","#idForm", function () { return true; }); //Passthrough
```

The idea is to retrigger the event but ensure you don't call the same handler.

There's a proof of concept at https://jsfiddle.net/2kbmcpa4/ (there's no actual ajax happening but the promise simulates that, note this example won't work in IE)

Answer (score -1):

Steps to solve the issue :

1. On actual form submit just block the event and make the rest call.
2. Based on response again dynamically resubmit by setting the allowSubmit flag.
3. Because flag is set on second submit, it doesn't prevent the form from submission. Reset the allowSubmit flag.

```js
(function() {
    var allowSubmit = false;
    $('body').on("submit", "#idForm", function(event) {
        var that = this;
        if (!allowSubmit) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post('php_file_rute.php', {
                action: 'functionName'
            }).done(function(result) {
                if (result == 1) {
                    if (functionNameInSameJSPage()) {
                        allowSubmit = true; // set the flag so next submit will not go though this flow
                        that.submit(); // dynamically trigger submit
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        } else {
            allowSubmit = false; // reset the flag
        }
    });
})();
```